# Controlling Access using htpasswd and htaccess

Tags: security, htaccess, password

I've got a bit of a peculiar problem on my site. I'm using a .htaccess and .htpasswd file to protect the root of the site. This works great, but when I try to view a video file on my site, it prompts for the password again. Is there something I can do so the only time a visitor is prompted to login is the first time he loads the page?
Thanks!
quark

Comment: Is the file within the folder you protected, or outside of it ?

Comment: Have in mind that if you switch from http to https you will have to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

By nature HTTP is stateless, which means that you'll be prompted to input the username and password every time you try to get something. However what happens is that your browser sends the username and password every request, so you don't have to fill them in every time. What happens here is that the browser doesn't re-send the information. Technically you're looking at a browser issue.

It might be necessary to use something different than htaccess/htpasswd. Embed the video in a page that uses a different way of authentication?